# oracledb connection issue : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_getConnection')

Tags: node.js, typescript, oracle, npm, node-oracledb

node oracle connection issue. It is already connected before in the same application but not working now. I updated the node version.

No issue in the connection string because the same connection working other application in the same server.

**node -v =v16.9.1

npm  -v =v7.21.1**

package json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/oracledb": "^5.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "group-by": "0.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "oracledb": "^5.1.0",
    "pg-promise": "^10.8.6",
    "tedious": "^9.2.3",
    "tedious-connection-pool": "^1.0.5"
  },
```

Code :

```
export const getOracleConnection = async () => {
   try {
      return await getConnection(POSTargetConfig)
   } catch (error) {
      console.log("Errorrrrrrrrr:  " + error.message)
      await TraceLog("Error", error.message);
      await onRejected();
   }
}

export const POSTargetConfig = {
  user: "name",
  password: 'pass',
  connectString: `(DESCRIPTION =
                  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =server.amazonaws.com)(PORT =1521))
                  (CONNECT_DATA =
                    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                    (SID =devid)
                  )
                )
                `
};
```

**Result Error:**

```
 Errorrrrrrrrr:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_getConnection')
```

Comment: How did you import the oracle-package? I always imported it like this `import oracledb from "oracledb";` also, did you test the Database-Url, i.e. with sql-developer?

Comment: A side comment: why not use node-oracledb 5.2 instead of 5.1?  Conversely did your app work _before_ you upgraded Node.js - or did you upgrade to see if the problem got resolved?

Comment: @EricKrg I used like this ` import { getConnection, OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT } from 'oracledb' `.  yes, I used to connect with sql-developer.

Comment: I almost have the same setup in a Project of mine, using oracledb 5.1.1 and node v.14.17.2, maybe you could remove the linebreaks in your db-url and try again or if that does not work downgrade node ?

Comment: @ChristopherJones: I tried with 5.2 also but the same result.  It's  working before my upgrade. I updated the node version for another project and came back to here then it is not working.  The connection issue occurs when I reinstall npm and npm typescript because now I take  `npm run build` to old working backup that is working with zero issue.

Comment: I compare the working one and non-working one, then I find only one difference is `  "typescript": "^4.3.5" `  changed to  ` "typescript": "^4.4.3" `.

Comment: What do you see when you start the app with `--experimental-modules` flag?

Comment: This is likely related to https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1408

Comment: Can you try the patch suggested in the GitHub issue and let us know if it fixes your problem? https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1408#issuecomment-937094099

Answer (score 0):

please check your connectivity hope you only one connection create becuase mongojs is

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).